# Why am I receiving "bound must be positive" error?

Tags: java, random

I am trying to write code that simulates a game of Scrabble.  I designed a class which should simulate a Scrabble bag, and I am trying to test it by printing the `tileID` in `main()` after choosing a random tile.  Whenever I run the code though, I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
    at hw3.RandomBag.randomPick(RandomBag.java:39)
    at hw3.RandomBag.main(RandomBag.java:59`
```

Can somebody tell me why I am receiving that error?

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomBag<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    
    // instance varibles
    private List<E> bag; // arraylist as the container
    private Random rand; // random number generator
    
    // constructors
    public RandomBag() { 
        bag = new ArrayList<E>();
        rand = new Random();    
    }
    
    public RandomBag(int seed) { 
        bag = new ArrayList<E>();
        rand = new Random(seed);
        
    }
    
    // returns the size of the bag
    public int size() { return this.bag.size(); }  
    
    public boolean isEmpty() { // returns true/false if the bag is/is not empty
        if (this.bag.isEmpty())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }  
    
    // adds the parameter element in the bag
    public void add (E element) {this.bag.add(element);} 
    
    // randomly selects an element using the random number generator 'rand' and removes that element from the bag, and returns the element
    public E randomPick() {
        
        int index = rand.nextInt(this.bag.size());
        E tileID = bag.remove(index);
        return tileID;
    } 
    
    // obtains an iterator for the bag, and returns it
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        // traverse bag using an iterator
        Iterator it = bag.iterator();
        return it;
    }
    
      //**
      //** main() for testing RandomBag<E>
      //**
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        RandomBag bag = new RandomBag();   
        
        Object tileID = bag.randomPick(); 
        System.out.println(tileID);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `this.bag.size()` is 0, you are passing an invalid argument to `nextInt()`.

This is clearly stated in the Javadoc :

> n the bound on the random number to be returned. **Must be positive**.

`nextInt(n)` returns a number between 0 and n-1. What do you expect `nextInt(0)` to return?

In your main method you are attempting to pick an element of an empty bag. It can't work. You should check the size of the bag before calling `randomPick()`. And `randomPick()` should probably throw an exception when the bag is empty.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    RandomBag bag = new RandomBag();   

    Object tileID = null;
    if (bag.size() > 0)
        tileID = bag.randomPick(); 
    System.out.println(tileID);

}
```

Comment: I get confused because even if I choose an arbitrary number and put it in place of `this.bag.size()`, I still get the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
 at hw3.RandomBag.randomPick(RandomBag.java:40)
 at hw3.RandomBag.main(RandomBag.java:59)
`

Comment: Although correct, I would argue that the Javadoc is not explicit enough. Is zero a positive number? It's not prefixed by a hyphen, so some might say yes. In other situations, there are both explicit positive and negative versions of 0. It might have been better for the docs to state "Must be a positive number, greater than 0".

Comment: @OmarN That's a completely different error. If your List is empty, trying to call `remove` for any index would result in `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You should make sure your List is not empty before calling `randomPick`. This way your original code will work.

Comment: @adelphus Positive means > 0, non negative means >= 0.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
```

Whenever bound is `zero` or `negative`, it is an illegal argument to `rand.nextInt()`. Make sure that `this.bag.size()` is never `zero`.

Comment: This makes sense, but what confuses me is even if I put an arbitrary number in place of `this.bag.size()`, I get the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
 at hw3.RandomBag.randomPick(RandomBag.java:40)
 at hw3.RandomBag.main(RandomBag.java:59)
`

Answer (score 2):

The error is happening because of the **Line 62** in your class:

```
int index = rand.nextInt(this.bag.size());
```

If you call this code with an empty bag, it will always return 0.

Next step is checking **line 387** of the class [`java.util.Random`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Random.java#Random.nextInt%28int%29):

```
if (bound <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadBound);
```

Since we are always getting 0 from `this.bag.size()`, it will always throw an exception.

To make it work, make sure to add elements to the bag, as in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    RandomBag bag = new RandomBag();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        bag.add(i); // adding elements
    }

    Object tileID = bag.randomPick();

    System.out.println(tileID);

}
```